# How to detect errors in forms using TextInputEditTexts

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-textinputlayout, android-textinputedittext

I have a form with many TextInputEditTexts. I use the method setError to display errors to the user. I need to continue with some code, if there are no errors. But how can I detect if there is no error ?

I know that I can detect if the TextInputEditText is empty and if the String contains spaces and so on, but is there a method to detect if there is an error shown in TextInputEditTexts, so that I don't need to implement it myself ?

Comment: Use Regular Expressions

Answer (score 0):

`TextInputLayout.error` returns the error if there is one, and null otherwise.

So, create a helper property you can use to check it:

```kotlin
val TextInputLayout.isError: Boolean get() = error != null
```

Or for the TextInputEditText itself:

```kotlin
val TextInputEditText.isError: Boolean 
    get() = parent.let { it is TextInputLayout && it.error != null }
```

For Java, you'd have to either test this every time:

```java
boolean isError = myTextInputLayout.getError() != null;

// or

Object parent = myEditText.getParent();
boolean isError = parent instanceof TextInputLayout && ((TextInputLayout) parent).getError() != null;
```

Or create a utility method in some utility class:

```java
public final class TextInputLayoutUtils {

    public static boolean isError(TextInputLayout layout) {
        return layout.getError() != null;
    }

    public static boolean isError(EditText editText) {
        Object parent = editText.getParent();
        return parent instanceof TextInputLayout && isError((TextInputLayout) parent);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Is there something like TextInputLayout.error for java too?

Comment: I updated it to show a Java solution.